# Sharepoint DateTimeControl not firing event when blanked

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have added the datetimecontrol to the screen (directly in the markup not dynamically) and the DateChanged event fires when a different date is selected but it does not fire when the date is blanked. Is there a way to solve this issues please? I would really need the event to fire when the date is blanked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working as follows:

```
     private void HookUpEvents()
            {            
                this.DateTimeControl.DateChanged += DateTimeControl_DateChanged;
                ((TextBox)this.DateTimeControl.Controls[0]).TextChanged += RxDatePicker_TextChanged;
            }

            void RxDatePicker_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)this.DateTimeControl.Controls[0]).Text))
                {
                    if (this.OnValueChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.OnValueChanged(sender, e);
                    }
                }
            }
 void DateTimeControl_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.OnValueChanged != null)
            {
                this.OnValueChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }
```